# enable user to connect to external pptp VPN server

Tags: linux, centos, iptables, vpn, pptp

I want to enable local user to connect to remote VPN server
I added those rules to the iptables but still not able to connect

```
-A OUTPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `iptables` rules are position-dependent, so without the output of `iptables -L -n -v` pasted into your question, we probably can't help much.

Comment: You added them? Like to the end? Like after the "drop all the other traffic" entry that you normally wuld have at the end?